# facebook api Campaign time_range

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Get data for a specified date.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/campaigns_id?fields=id,name,delivery_status,effective_status,status,spent,daily_budget,frequency,result,insights.time_range({'since':'2020-02-20','until':'2020-02-20'}){impressions,inline_link_clicks,cost_per_inline_link_click,cpm,inline_link_click_ctr}&access_token=XXXXX&time_range({'since':'2020-02-20','until':'2020-02-20'})
```

I get data for all the time.

How can I get data for a specified date ?

Answer (score 0):

Time ranges can only be applied to "insights" edge here
You can achieve this with this call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/{your-campaign-id}?fields=id,name,effective_status,status,daily_budget,insights.time_range({'since':'2020-02-20','until':'2020-02-20'}){impressions,inline_link_clicks,cost_per_inline_link_click,cpm,inline_link_click_ctr}&access_token=XXXXX
```

You only need your first "time_range" in your query

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I will receive according to these indicators (spent, daily_budget, frequency, result) for all the time, but I would like for the selected time.